# Можно ли добавить дополнительное поле в форму подключения сервиса телефонии?

Tags: moysklad-phone-api

При подключении к серверу телефонии необходимо передать Ключ АТС.
В интерфейсе подключения Phone API при нажатии кнопки "Подключить" можно указать адрес сервера телефонии и внутренние номера. Можно ли в этот интерфейс добавлять дополнительные поля с дополнительными параметрами? Например "Ключ АТС".

[image: Подключение Phone API]

Answer (score 0):

Нет, никаких дополнительных полей передавать нельзя.
Для данной интеграции подразумевается, что все дополнительные данные должны хранится у провайдера телефонии. С нашей стороны мы предоставляем только API по созданию и отображению на нашей стороне входящих звонков и некоторого метода вызова внешнего провайдера для создания исходящего звонка. 
Я бы предложил вам постмотреть в сторону указания данных параметров в адресе провайдера, именно по нему и происходит исходящий вызов.